# How do I get the actual file from an Input type file element?

Tags: reactjs, input, socket.io

var file = e.target.files[0];

or

var file = e.target.value;

I'm using React and Socket io to try to sent images over chat.   All I've been able to get is the file path not the actual file.  I've never handled file inputs so I'm trying to figure out how to take that file and convert it to a binary string I can send over socket io.

help?  any packages you would recommend?

Comment: Have you tried any of the existing react packages?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-file-input this one seems to allow converting the input to binary, give it a shot and let us know how it goes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get file from input for example you can fire handler on `onChange` event. After this you must put your file from input(e.target.file[0] or loop if files many) to [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and extract blob from file. Next you can send extracted blob through socket, if blob is too large you can slice it to chunks.

There is example of code:

```
const readBlob = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = e => {
    resolve(e.target.result);
  };

  reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

Sorry for my English!)

Comment: Useful answer that helped me a lot :) But you might want to link to the English doc and not the Russian one!

Comment: @user1339253 Good catch. I have edited the link. Thank you.

Comment: Btw it's `files` (plural)  not `file` according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#technical_summary on the `event.target` object.